Creating contextual prefLabels
Is there a way to contextualise SKOS/RDF labels in the same language so they are used only in certain circumstances?
I have a range a conceptSchemes that contain concepts where the preferred labels differ by context and usage, even in the same language. For example, regional variations or differences between industries.
A borehole is locally known as a Well in the petroleum industry, but a Drillhole in the minerals industry, and a Bore if used to access groundwater.
In Australia the size of beer glasses differ by state, and they commonly conflict.



Size
Name(NSW)
Name(QLD)
Name(VIC)
Name(SA)




285mL
middy
pot
pot
schooner


425mL
schooner
schooner
schooner
pint


570mL
pint
pint
pint
imperial pint



So a hypothetical concept would look like
ausBeerSize:285ml a skos:Concept ; 
    placeholder:other-rdf-stuff ;
    skos:prefLabel
        "middy"@en^^(some context to say use this in NSW),
        "pot"@en^^(some context to say use this in QLD),
        "pot"@en^^(some context to say use this in VIC),
        "schooner"@en^^(some context to say use this in SA) .

^^(some context…) could be a literal or another RDF entity such as a concept scheme or ontology containing states and territories of Australia.

without introducing entities per context I'd say a similar but still different option is what the SKOS extension SKOS-XL gives your for labels - here the labels itself are entities, so you could easily append a context property for later use.

Without adding some additional entities or label entities via SKOS-XL, I don't see how it could be done in such a way that you do not encoded semantics in the label - and nobody should or wants to do this as querying in textual data is probably not what people consider efficient of smart.

If you do not need to interpret the "context" of the label in any way through RDF, you could still use language tags for it, as it is the only way that allows you to stick to using skos:prefLabel. This gives you these fields to use:

langtag = (language
           ["-" script]
           ["-" region]
           *("-" variant)
           *("-" extension)
           ["-" privateuse])


language is obviously en, script is left implicit (Latin), and region is Australia (AU). There is no applicable variant as defined by the IANA Language Subtag Registry that could identify Australian regions or dialects, so we need to look in extension. Extension U is what we can use here, but we need to navigate into the CLDR, published here. Inside core.zip/common/bcp47/variant.xml, we find sd ‒ region subdivision:

Valid unicode_subdivision_subtag for the region subtag as specified in LDML, based on subdivisionContainment data in supplementalData, prefixed by the associated unicode_region_subtag

In core.zip/common/supplemental/subdivisions.xml, we find the Australian regions:

<subgroup type="AU" contains="auact aunsw aunt auqld ausa autas auvic auwa"/>


In core.zip/common/subdivisions/en.xml, we find their names:

<!-- AU : Australia -->
<subdivision type="auact">Australian Capital Territory</subdivision>
<subdivision type="aunsw">New South Wales</subdivision>
<subdivision type="aunt">Northern Territory</subdivision>
<subdivision type="auqld">Queensland</subdivision>
<subdivision type="ausa">South Australia</subdivision>
<subdivision type="autas">Tasmania</subdivision>
<subdivision type="auvic">Victoria</subdivision>
<subdivision type="auwa">Western Australia</subdivision>


This is enough to express your example:
ausBeerSize:285ml skos:prefLabel
  "middy"@en-AU-u-sd-aunsw ,
  "pot"@en-AU-u-sd-auqld ,
  "pot"@en-AU-u-sd-auvic ,
  "schooner"@en-AU-u-sd-ausa .

The AU subtag is optional (since it is implied by sd), but may be included for compatibility. There are also other options for selecting currency, timezone, units of measurement, numeric system, and so on.
I could not find any extension for specifying a particular register or industry slang, so you are left with using privateuse subtags, forming language tags such as en-AU-x-petroleum, en-AU-x-minerals, en-AU-x-water, or any other you wish. Just note that these subtags are not easily "transferrable" to any other system since they are private-use. You can however add the description of those language tags in a meaningful way by describing "en-AU-x-petroleum"^^xsd:language.
